# Expressing the solution to a rational expression in radical form

Tags: radicals, cubics, radical-equations

I'm trying to find the solution to this equation

$$
-\frac{3}{r} + \frac{8}{r^3} = \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}
$$

but I haven't been able to find a solution in radical form. Although I've found the solutions as decimals, I am looking for a solution in radical form. What are the solutions to this equation expressed as radicals?

Comment: Lookup solutions to the [cubic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano's_formula). And btw, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax primer to help with math formatting.

Comment: How about rewrite the equation using cubes involving radical of $2$ ?

Comment: casus irreducibilis, without complex numbers not possible. Approximation one root $-\frac{18}{97}(53+17\sqrt{2})$